# trying to run code for x64 machine on x32 with python 2.7.8

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

the code im running is but i suppose it's because i am running it on x32 bit any idea how to get this to run ?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from statistics import mean

def threshold(imgArray):
    balanceAr = []
    newArray = imgArray

    for eachRow in imgArray:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y,eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
            balanceAr.append(avgNum)

    balance = (lambda x, y:x+y,balanceAr[:3])/len(balanceAr[:3])

    for eachRow in newAr:
        for eachPix in eachRow:
            if reduce(lambda x, y:x+y,eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3]) > balance:
                eachPix[0] = 255
                eachPix[1] = 255
                eachPix[2] = 255
                eachPix[3] = 255
            else:
                eachPix[0] = 0
                eachPix[1] = 0
                eachPix[2] = 0
                eachPix[3] = 255
    return newAr


i = Image.open('test.png')
iar = np.array(i)


threshold(iar)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6),(0,0),rowspan=4,colspan=3)


ax1.imshow(iar)


plt.show()
```

the error which i am getting is

line 13, in threshold
avgNum = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y,eachPix[:3])/len(eachPix[:3])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: eachPix seems to be a scalar variable and not a list. You can't have access to its indices when it's not a list.

Comment: any suggestions how to get it working?

Comment: It looks as though your code is designed for RGB images, which are represented as 3D (rows, columns, rgb) arrays, whereas you are passing it a monochrome image which is converted to a 2D (rows, colums) array. What is `iar.shape`?

Comment: a snapshot i have taken with my webcam and converted it to gray 50x50 pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i had to use opencv instead and it works ok but not very accurate

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.png')

grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow('threshold',threshold)
cv2.imwrite("11.png", threshold)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```